# What is the maximum number of points on a plane such that some other point A is the nearest neighbor for all of them?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Point $A$ on the plane is given. How many other points can be placed on this plane under the condition that $A$ is the nearest neighbor for any of these points?

I can think of a regular pentagon with $A$ as its center, its vertices being the $5$ points in question, but are there any configurations that include more points?

Comment: Five is the maximum because for any two points X and Y from the configuration, the angle XAY has to exceed 60. This question is more suitable for math.stackexchange

Comment: @mathworker21, if it were less than that, then $X$ and $Y$ would be closer to each other than to $A$.

Comment: To add a little more detail, $|AX| < |XY|$ and $|AY| < |XY|$ since $A$ is nearest neighbor to $X$ and $Y$, so $XY$ is the longest edge in triangle $AXY$, so $\angle XAY$ is the smallest angle. Since the sum of the angles in a triangle is $180$, this means $\angle XAY < 60$.

Comment: i misread the problem, but thanks

Comment: If you weaken *the* nearest neighbor to *a* nearest neighbor, you can use a regular hexagon with $A$ at its center.

Comment: You may prove that there may maximum 5 points by drawing circles around the points passing through $A$, which doesn't include any other point.

Comment: This seems like a reformulation of the kissing number problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses! It was really helpful.

Comment: In the comments, it is stated that 5 points are the maximal number of such points. But what about the following configuration: let A be the center of the unit circle, take 4 points on the circle at the north, south, and east and west 'poles'. The next 4 points are the same on the circle of radius 1/3 around A. These are already 8 points, and of course, it can be continued to infinity. Or I just didn't understand the question

Comment: @EpsilonNet In your construction, the nearest point to a point $p$ on the outer circle is the point $p'$ on the inner circle in between $p$ and $A$.